# Bulk Create Test Suite & Test Plan and Bulk attach Test Plan with Test Suite in ADO

Tags: azure, azure-devops, test-plan

We are trying to bulk import multiple test suites and test plans in Azure DevOps. ADO gives option to bulk import test cases for a given Test Suite, but I can't find an option to bulk import all test suites and test cases with test cases associated to test suites. As of now, we have to run bulk import for each test suite, i.e. if we have 300 test suites with 7 test cases under each, we have to run bulk import 300 times.

Please help.

Thanks,
Shubham Gupta

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go through this page first there are summarized all available options which are supported right now:

[Copy or clone test plans, test suites, and test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/copy-clone-test-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

And here are few options for you:

Have test suits in hierarchy

- Your_Test_plan

  - Parent_Suite

    - 1.Suite

      - child_suite
    - 2.Suite

      - child_suite
    - ...
    - N.Suite

And then You can use Import tool, it either let's you to pick just the lowest in hierarchy or you can copy from the top.

[image: In your Test plan click on dots by test suite and pick import test suits]

If you want to copy whole Plan there is an option too

[image]

Otherwise there is an option to use official REST VSTS API, so you can make script which does it for you.

- [Microsoft REST VSTS documentation - clone test suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-suite-clone/clone-test-suite?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#request-body)
- [Microsoft REST VSTS documentation - clone test plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-plan-clone/clone-test-plan?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)